# Why can't I access the firebase variable?

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, phonegap

In my PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile app, I am initializing Firebase successfully and I can access it no problem from my index.js. However, when I load a new a new html page which has its own previously loaded js (was loaded by index.html), it's unable to access the firebase variable.

Here's the kicker... the issue ONLY occurs on iOS. When I run my app in Chrome, it's all perfectly functional but once compiled and installed on device it chokes trying to access firebase on the second page.

Comment: I Created an App using all your Tags [Bakwas](https://github.com/fareed543/Bakwas). Hope You love it

Comment: You have to Initialize in every page. or keep the script in a file and use that script in every page.